# TeXmaker for plain TeX

Tags: editors, texmaker, plain-tex

Sorry if this has already been asked, but, if there is something similar like this TeXmaker for plain TeX?

Comment: You can use several editors with plain: it's just a question of setting the approach binary linked to the 'typeset' or 'build' button. Some (WinEdt, TeXworks, ...) have separate 'plain' and 'LaTeX' buttons: could you give a bit more detail on what is required?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 5):

the programs `tex`, `pdftex` or `luatex` are not directly supported by TeXmaker. Open the menue for User Commands and then create `TeX` with the command

```
pdftex %.tex
```

Restart TeXmaker and the new option should be seen in the menu for the different programs.

Comment: Or, if you use it exclusively, you can simply *change* the `pdflatex` command to `pdftex` so that you can use the F6 key as if you are using `pdflatex`.